# Best alternative to the 'title' attribute for storing data, like alternative meanings of words

Tags: jquery, html

I'm going to use jquery to show alternative meanings for words not everyone would immediately know or understand. For a really bad example: "Johnny is a little boy." A user could mark a checkbox to turn on a mode where it would now be: "Johnny is a little (tiny, small, short) boy." Again, very simple example. I don't want to use the `title` attribute because it pops up that little ugly tooltip. Some might be okay with that, I'm not.

**What would be the best attribute, or method of doing this? Creating my own attribute? What are the benefits and pitfalls?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<span data-easy="tiny, not large" class="easy"> small </span>
```

use jQuerys data, http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

maby use CSS to display them:

```
span.makeeasy[data-easy]:after { content: " (" attr(data-easy) ")"; }
```

then put the content in a DIV and add the 'makeeasy' class to display the values. (you might need a fallback for older brwsers)

Comment: `::after` not `:after`

Answer (score 2):

This is probably an appropriate use for the [HTML 5 data- attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/). You can define your own attribute, such as `data-translation`, and use it like this:

```
Johnny is a <span data-translation="tiny, small, short">little</span> boy.
```

You can then write some code to take the data from the `data-translation` attribute and insert it after the `span` element when the user enables translations.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a definition list (`dl`) with `dd` for definitions and `dt` for terms: http://w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try out jQuery data: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/