# Accessibility using title attribute for truncated text

Tags: html, css, accessibility, semantic-markup

I have a table cell with max-width set and if the text within the cell is too long, it gets truncated with ellipsis.

Therefore, would using the title attribute to display the full text be an appropriate (accessible) solution?

Comment: With text-overflow, it's not easy to determine when the text is truncated though, so you won't know which cells to give the title to.

Comment: In short, no. The `title` attribute is not reliably announced by screen readers:  http://blog.paciellogroup.com/2010/11/using-the-html-title-attribute/

Answer (score 5):

If the text is truncated by means of CSS's `text-overflow: ellipsis`: **Yes, the `title` attribute is a working solution for screen readers**.

It does not even matter if it's being read by screen readers, since the original (visually truncated) text will be fully read.

On the other hand, [title attributes are not accessible by keyboard, touch screen and other means](https://developer.paciellogroup.com/blog/2010/11/using-the-html-title-attribute/).

For your case I would see the following solutions:

- use `title` if the truncated text is but a preview and linked with another view showing the full version
- Make the text expandable inline, by means of a toggle like `…`
- Provide a keyboard and screen reader accessible tooltip that expands the text in a layover

In all cases screen reader users will already have access to the full text without additional interaction.

Comment: If the text is truncated with CSS it is already accessible to screen readers. https://butterpep.com/line-clamp-overflow-ellipsis.html

Comment: Thanks for your comment. That's what I tried to express in the second and again in the last paragraph.

Answer (score -1):

<strike>Well, in my opinion it would be the appropriate solution because users just often take the mouse over the text and wait for the hidden text to popup. I saw many of them including my sister who is not at all in these type of things. She just hover overs a text and then wait for the text to come up and when it does not she just says "Oh god! Why???". So in my opinion it would the appropriate way.</strike>

One more thing, you can catch the user's attention by styling your title attribute/tooltip a bit.

**EDIT:** *@steveax* said that `title` attribute is not good to use so I recommend you seeing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675432/best-alternative-to-the-title-attribute-for-storing-data-like-alternative-mea) question. The question has a type of CSS approach so it will be easier for you to style it :)

Comment: I am curious: How can you style the title attribute ?

Comment: Ah, I see. You were talking about a tooltip plugin. I thought you meant actually style the 'title' attribute.

Comment: hehe, obviously bro, how can we style the title attribute :P

Comment: I thought you were an HTML-Ninja :P

Comment: The `title` attribute is not reliably announced by screenreaders.

Comment: @steveax screen readers that read the content of the element, rather than what's displayed on the screen, should have no problems with ellipsis'ed text.

Comment: @ExpertSystem you cannot style the `title` attribute directly. That's controlled by the system and browser

Comment: -1 advocating use of `title`, incorrectly suggesting the `title` could be styled, and for leaving bad info in

Answer (score -2):

I will suggest to you https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/tooltip.
It will work in all environments.

Comment: Have you tested whether that leads to an *accessible* tooltip? Can keyboard users access the information? Is it read out be screen readers?

Comment: I have not tested but keyboard users can access the information, screen readers do not read out this, and more testing you can do using CodePen provided in the below link.